# Criar uma Imagem embutida no corpo da mensagem de e-mail

Tags: php, imagem, email, phpmailer

Bom dia a todos.

Criei um e-mail marketing para enviar aos meus contatos com layout de fim de ano.

Em fim, reparei que o modo como envio a imagem em html:

`<img src="http://www.site.com.br/imagens/imagem1.jpg"/>`

funciona perfeitamente. Porém, no outlook do windows, ele pede que o usuário libere essa imagem para que ela apareça. Não vejo isso como um problema sério, pois se o usuário te conhece, e realmente quer receber seus e-mails, ele irá liberar.

Porém, eu trabalho com alguns clientes que são muito leigos e gostaria de evitar isso.

Reparei que com o gmail você consegue embutir uma imagem no corpo do e-mail e o outlook do windows, de alguma forma, não entende que aquilo é uma imagem. Basta você arrastar uma imagem ao corpo do email do gmail que ela será embutida.

Minha dúvida é:
**Como posso fazer isso com o php? Qual é a técnica usada pelo gmail?**

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Isso é uma questão de "segurança" do outlook, quando alguém receber um e-mail marketing seu ela tem que selecionar a opção "sempre exibir conteúdo deste destinatário" para que isso não ocorra mais.
Infelizmente não creio que existe uma "técnica" para burlar isso, porque o outlook bloqueia todo e qualquer tipo de imagem exceto as que o usuário autorizar.

Comment: Eu sei @RafaelAcioly, porém, quando você envia uma imagem embutita pelo gmail o outlook não reconhece que é uma imagem. E a imagem aparece no e-mail do outlook sem precisar ser liberada pelo usuário. Eu queria entender como funciona isso.

Comment: Veja, não acho que isso seja um hack, se não o gmail, com certeza não faria isso.

Comment: Para falar a verdade, eu nem sei se é uma imagem embutida realmente, o que eu sei é que quando é enviado pelo gmail no corpo do email uma imagem, ela é mostrada pelo outlook sem precisar de liberação.

Comment: Qualquer webmail bloqueia imagens ou exibição de conteúdo externo por padrão. Não é algo do outlook. Mas é possível enviar enviar a imagem embutida no corpo. A imagem deve estar como anexo e então faz o link direto para a imagem em anexo.

Comment: Então @DanielOmine, não sei se você tem gmail, mas no gmail, quando eu coloco a imagem no corpo da mensagem o outlook nao bloqueia, ou qualquer email nao bloqueia. Faz um teste. Queria saber como eles fazem. =/

Comment: Eu acredito que quando você insere a imagem no corpo, ela deixa de ser uma imagem, de alguma forma, vira um código, sei lá.. rsrsrs

Comment: É isso mesmo. O corpo do email codifica para um formato definido no cabeçalho.  Há diversos formatos. Talvez o que vc viu seja base64.

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre isso @DanielOmine. Obrigado